# MySQL join on substring is slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query where I do a join on a substring, the problem is that this is really slow to complete. Is there a more effecient way to write this?

```
SELECT *, SUM(s.pris*s.antall) AS total, SUM(s.antall) AS antall
FROM ecs_statistikk AS s 
JOIN butikk_ordre AS bo ON ordreId=bo.ecs_ordre_id AND butikkNr=bo.site_id 
JOIN ecs_supplier AS l ON SUBSTRING( s.artikkelId, 1,2 )=l.lev_id
WHERE s.salgsDato>='2016-6-01' AND s.salgsDato<='2016-09-30'
GROUP BY l.lev_id ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: Although this doesn't affect performance, it is really bad practice to use `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support function indices, so if you can't find a way to join without substring, then the peformance may not be ideal.

Comment: I don't run SELECT *, just thought it would be easier for you to read.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is not strictly true anymore

Comment: @Shadow Please explain how an index could be used for the join in the OP.

Comment: Seems like a table design issue. Fix it and you won't have any performance problems!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen generated column + index (or simulate a generated column with triggers). But I'm not sure the OP needs that.

Comment: I can type at 120 words per minute. In doing so, I make hundreds of mistakes, but it sure is fast. Is my 'performance' unaffected by the fact that the output is gobbledigook?

Comment: @jarlh Unfortunatly, I have to work with the data as it is.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would check indexes.  For this query:

```
SELECT *, SUM(s.pris*s.antall) AS total, SUM(s.antall) AS antall
FROM ecs_statistikk s JOIN
     butikk_ordre bo
     ON s.ordreId = bo.ecs_ordre_id AND
        s.butikkNr = bo.site_id JOIN
     ecs_supplier l
     ON SUBSTRING(s.artikkelId, 1, 2 ) = l.lev_id
WHERE s.salgsDato >= '2016-06-01' AND s.salgsDato <= '2016-09-30'
GROUP BY l.lev_id
ORDER BY total DESC ;
```

You want indexes on `ecs_statistikk(salgsDato, ordreId, butikkNr, artikkelId)`, `butikk_ordre(ecs_ordre_id, site_id)`, and ecs_supplier(lev_id)`.

Next, I would question whether you need the last `JOIN` at all.  Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT LEFT(s.artikkelId, 2) as lev_id, *,
       SUM(s.pris*s.antall) AS total, SUM(s.antall) AS antall
FROM ecs_statistikk s JOIN
     butikk_ordre bo
     ON s.ordreId = bo.ecs_ordre_id AND
        s.butikkNr = bo.site_id
WHERE s.salgsDato >= '2016-06-01' AND s.salgsDato <= '2016-09-30'
GROUP BY LEFT(s.artikkelId, 2)
ORDER BY total DESC ;
```

Comment: Good point about the need for a join. Unfortunatly I have to check if lev_id exists in the other table as well. I think I have made the correct indexes, but still it takes 40 seconds to complete.